# Ajax error when trying to add another paragraph

Tags: 8, users, forms, ajax, paragraphs

Drupal 8.9 and paragraph 8.x-1.11

My issue is that Ajax breaks when altering the #validate form. This is an issue for any form! It may have to do with my ajax, but here is my setup.

I have a paragraph type:

contact_information

- field_phone_number (telephone from core)
- field_type_of_phone (text_plain)

I have a custom module. In this custom module I am creating a form_alter on /user/register

I have:

```
function telephone_alter_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id ){
  //$form['#validate'] = array();  //commenting this in or out doesn't help
  $form['#validate'][] = 'telephone_alter_test_validate';
  //$form['field_phone']['widget']['#element_validate'][] = 'telephone_alter_test_validate';
}

function telephone_alter_test_validate($form, &$form_state) {
   echo "hi"; //prints hi, but ajax breaks
}
```

The validation works, prints out debugging. However, when I try to add another paragraph element, it does nothing. This is for any form. I have tried this on other forms like adding a basic page and trying to call an alter function!

the Ajax error displayed is:

```
[{"command":"insert","method":"prepend","selector":null,"data":"\u003Cdiv data-drupal-messages\u003E\n  \u003Cdiv class=\u0022messages__wrapper\u0022\u003E\n \u003Cdiv class=\u0022alert alert-danger alert-dismissible\u0022 role=\u0022alert\u0022 aria-label=\u0022Error message\u0022\u003E\n \u003Cbutton type=\u0022button\u0022 role=\u0022button\u0022 class=\u0022close\u0022 data-dismiss=\u0022alert\u0022 aria-label=\u0022Close\u0022\u003E\u003Cspan aria-hidden=\u0022true\u0022\u003E\u0026times;\u003C\/span\u003E\u003C\/button\u003E\n \u003Ch2 class=\u0022sr-only\u0022\u003EError message\u003C\/h2\u003E\n \u003Cp\u003EAn unrecoverable error occurred. The uploaded file likely exceeded the maximum file size (40 MB) that this server supports.\u003C\/p\u003E\n \u003C\/div\u003E\n    \u003C\/div\u003E\n\u003C\/div\u003E\n","settings":null}]
```

The Ajax error is key, because if I create an alter form for any other page, I still get the error.

Any help is great! Thank you! I can provide more info if needed

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.
It turned out every time a paragraph is added the validation method runs.
In your case, `echo` is illegal and it stops the following process. Try replacing it with php `error_log` or Devel debug functions.

Comment: After finding out about [Xdebug](https://xdebug.org/docs/install), life has been so much simpler. I would almost say having Xdebug is required to break and debug on ajax calls.

Comment: Also Devel Debug Log module can debug ajax callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

If you "initialize" the **#validate** form array key, you will loose the validations set by other modules (like paragraphs). This is bad practice and can break things.

Add your custom validation method like this:

```
function telephone_alter_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id ){
  $form['#validate'][] = 'telephone_alter_test_validate';
}
```

Comment: I removed the initialization to no avail :(

here is what kint::dump($form['#validate']); prints after I add my function.

0 => string (14) "::validateForm"  **newline**
1 => string (29) "telephone_alter_test_validate" . Ajax still break and I can't add more paragraphs.